# Pointer references mixing '*' and ' ->' syntax confusion

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I'm not a C developer by trade... truth-be-told I'm not a developer by trade, so the terminology I use may be incorrect.

I have spent the last hour or so reading about `define` statements and then about `pointer` references and am quite confused by the following instance.

Given:

```
#define get_u_int16_t (X,O)  (*(u_int16_t *)(((u_int8_t *)X) + O))

if (get_u_int16_t(packet->payload, 0) == htons(0x0004)) {
//do something
return;
}
```

Does this mean that `get_u_int16_t(packet->payload, 0)` splits the data referred to by the `packet->payload` pointer into 8 bit sections, and returns the first 8 bits (due to the `+ 0`)?

This is an example from a single portion of the nDPI libraries which I'm attempting to reserve, [afp.c](https://svn.ntop.org/svn/ntop/trunk/nDPI/src/lib/protocols/afp.c).

[note]

[htons()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) is a function that takes a `word` (16 bits) in host byte order (little endian on most machines, or big endian on big endian machines) and converts it to a `word` in network byte order (always big endian).  In this case, the `word` at offset 0 of `packet->payload` (thanks AndreyT!) would return a `word`in big endian, so the ntop devs decided to use `htons()` to convert a given value (in this case a one of the byte patterns that determine if a flow is of Apple Filing Protocol) that is little endian to the big endian of the network stack.

[more]

I had moved [some questions to a forum that is more conducive to fuzzy questions to have some technicalities understood](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7473743-2bf4-4cfd-9255-77546317a1ed/how-do-i-convert-a-little-endian-used-in-htons-or-htonl-to-32bit-chars) that might prove useful for people dealing with similar situations in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but not entirely.

The `u_int8_t` type serves as an addressing unit. It is basically a "byte". So the

```
((u_int8_t *)X) + O)
```

part simply selects the location at byte-offset `O` from the beginning of the memory block pointed by `X`. That's where the role of `u_int8_t` type ends.

Then the `*(u_int16_t *)` part interprets that memory location as an unsigned 16-bit word.

So, you got everything right except that the macro "returns" a 16-bit value (not 8-bit value) stored at address `X + O`. In your specific example the macro is used to read an unsigned 16-bit value stored at the very beginning (offset `0`) of memory block `packet->payload`.

Note that a macro written in this fashion evaluates to an *lvalue*, meaning that it can also be used for *writing* 16 bit data at specific byte-offset in the given memory block, e.g.

```
get_u_int16_t(packet->payload, 0) = 42;
```

would write `42` into the 16-bit word residing at the very beginning of memory block `packet->payload`.

Comment: Excellent, easily understood answer!  Thanks so much!